# Curl command in Bash script returns no URL specified

Tags: bash, curl

Trying to run a curl command to a test page results in "no URL specified!" when attempting to run via a bash script. This is a test that runs through a proxy (1.2.3.4 in the code example)

The command runs as expected from the command line. I've tried a few variations of quotes around the components of the command however still manage the same "no URL specified" result.

```sh
echo $(curl -x http://1.2.3.4:80 https://example.company.com)
```

The expected result is an HTML file, however instead the above issue is found *only* when run from this small bash script file.

The command itself runs just fine as "curl -x http://1.2.3.4:80 https://example.company.com" from the command line.

Appreciate in advance any help you can provide!

---

I have literally edited it down to the following. Everything else is commented out. Still the same error.

```sh
#!/bin/bash

curl -x http://1.2.3.4:80 https://example.company.com
```

Comment: Using `echo $(somecommand)` is almost always an antipattern; just run the command directly. But that shouldn't cause this problem. Please provide a [minimal reproducable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). That is, make a copy of your script, and remove irrelevant part of it (testing as you go to make sure it still shows the problem -- if the problem vanishes, whatever you just took out wasn't actually irrelevant and needs to be put back). When it's down to just the bare minimum needed to show the problem, edit it into your question (in code format).

Comment: are you sure that the space between the proxy string and the URL is actually a space inside the script?

Comment: @root somehow that was indeed the problem. I assume caused by doing EOL conversion in Notepad++ to Unix friendly? Either way, deleting the "space" and re-adding it resolved the issue. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

In your example you want to use double quotes around the subshell and single qutes for the curl parameters

Make sure to set the correct shebang (`#!/bin/bash`).

You could also try to run it as:

```
cat <(curl -x http://1.2.3.4:80 https://example.company.com)
```

However I am not able to reproduce your example